# CircuiTikZ Nfet Solid line

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I'm trying to replace the switches in my schematic with mosfets.

My switches look like this:

```
\draw(0,0) to[nos=$S_1$] (2,0);  %S1
```

[image]

And my mosfet looks like this:

```
\draw(0,0) to node[nigfete, bodydiode, rotate=90, nogate]{$S_1$} (2,0);
```

[image]

My issue is that I have a solid line on the mosfet, where as the symbol that the manual shows (and how I usually see mosfets) don't have that solid line:

[image]

Also the description S_1 is rotated as well.

Am I using the node incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the "path" style for transistors (look at section 3.18.2 in new `circuitikz` manual). Unfortunately, labels for transistors are buggy (it's in the manual, but with the `bodydiode` are even more buggy), so you have to add them by hand.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
%\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikzgit}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[
    ]
        \draw (0,0)
        to [Tnigfete, nogate, bodydiode, invert, name=s1, -*] ++(2,0)
        coordinate(one)
        to [Tnigfete, nogate, bodydiode, invert, name=s2] ++(2,0);
        \draw (s1.center) node[above=0.4cm] {S1}
              (s2.center) node[above=0.4cm] {S2};
        \draw (one) to[short, *-o] ++(0,1);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

For the rotation of labels, there is almost nothing we can do --- you have  to rotate them back with `rotatebox` or `scalebox` (see section 3.2.1 --- mirroring and flipping --- in the manual, and 3.27.3 --- chips rotation).

Answer (score 3):

`draw` command draws a line between to nodes. Define the mosfets as `node`.

```
     \documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
     \usepackage[oldvoltagedirection]{circuitikz}

     \begin{document}
     \begin{circuitikz}[american]
     \node (0,0)  [nigfete,bodydiode,rotate=90, nogate,
label={[shift={(0,0.4cm)}]$S_1$}](nigf1){}--(2,0) node[nigfete,bodydiode,rotate=90, nogate,
label={[shift={(0,0.4cm)}]$S_2$}](nigf2){};
    \draw (nigf1.S) to (nigf2.D);
    \draw ($(nigf1.S)!0.5!(nigf2.D)$) to [short,*-]+(90:1);
    \end{circuitikz}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why does the first mosfet have a coordinate (2,0) and the second one doesn't? Or is the (2,0) actually the coordinates of the 2nd mosfet?

Comment: @Julian - yea.  There are severak ways ti locate a node similar to `to`.  For example `\path (0,0) -- (2,0) node[midway, nigfete, bodydiode, rotate=90, nogate, name=S1]{$S_1$};`.

Comment: Is there a way to add the lines from and to the node without using an extra statement? `\path(0,0) -- (2,0) node[midway, nigfete, bodydiode, rotate=90, nogate](s1){$S_1$} ;` gives me the switch in the right position but not lines from and to the switch. `\draw (0,0) to (s1.D); \draw (s1.S) to (2,0);` works but seems unwieldly.

Comment: Also the Annotations are still rotated, is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

To use a tripole as a dipole you need to add T to the name.  Also, the options for `to` are not the same as the options for `node`.  Finally, the labels are buggy (as mentioned in the manual).

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[oldvoltagedirection]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
\draw (0,0) to[Tnigfete, bodydiode, invert, n=S1, l={eek!}] (2,0) (S1.north east) node[above]{$S1$};
%\draw[red] (S1.south west) -- (S1.south) -- (S1.south east) -- (S1.east) -- (S1.north east) -- (S1.north) -- (S1.north west) -- (S1.west) -- cycle;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: is -- the same thing as to?

Comment: Not quite.  `to` is more powerful, but both connect two coordinates with a path segment.